# Aggregate within a ROW in a SELECT projection list is not allowed

Tags: informix

I am trying to move the database from `Informix Dynamic Server 14.10.FC7W1AEE` to `Informix Dynamic Server 14.10.FC10AEE` (both RHEL 8, but different machines), so from PortMaster 7 to 10. Everything works well except the following command for a view.

```
    create view "dbo".dirdoc1 (
        typv,predpona,eecyear,eecnum,popivaz
    ) as select
        x0.typv ,
        min(row(x1.eecyear ,
        x1.eecnum ,
        x1.predpona )::eec ).predpona ,
        min(row(x1.eecyear ,
        x1.eecnum ,
        x1.predpona )::eec ).eecyear ,
        min(row(x1.eecyear ,
        x1.eecnum ,
        x1.predpona )::eec ).eecnum ,
        max(x0.popivaz ) 
    from
        "dbo".typv x0 ,
    outer("dbo".dirdoc x1 ) where
        (
            x0.typv = x1.typv 
        ) 
    group by
        x0.typv ;
```

I receive an error:

> Aggregate within a ROW in a SELECT projection list is not allowed

When I run the command with just one of the aggregates, e.g.:

```
select 
        x0.typv,
        --min(row(x1.eecyear,x1.eecnum,x1.predpona)::eec).predpona,
        --min(row(x1.eecyear,x1.eecnum,x1.predpona)::eec).eecyear,
        min(row(x1.eecyear,x1.eecnum,x1.predpona)::eec).eecnum ,
        max(x0.popivaz) 
    from
```

it works, but when I use 2 or more `min()` columns it shows me an error.

There is no issue when I run the command (or just the SELECT part) on FC7. When I run it on FC10, I receive the error above.

I was checking release notes of FC8, FC9 and FC10, onconfig files and ENV variables... Everything looks the same (as it can be on different machines).

Where there any changes between FC7 and FC10, that may cause this issue?

Here are steps on how to replicate the issue. These steps work in `FC7W1`, but do not work in `FC10`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.typv (
    typv char(8) NOT NULL,
    popivaz varchar(254) NOT NULL,
    poznvaz varchar,
    nazevc varchar,
    snp smallint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    peca smallint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
    uveu smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (typv) CONSTRAINT typv_pk
);
###
create table dbo.dirdoc
  (
    typv char(8) not null ,
    eecyear datetime year to year not null ,
    eecnum integer not null ,
    oj char(14),
    predpona varchar(7)
        default 'EEC' not null ,
    celex char(10),

    check (((((oj MATCHES 'OJ [0-9][0-9]/[CL] [1-9][0-9/ ][0-9/ ][0-9/ ][0-9/ ][0-9/ ]'
              ) AND ((oj MATCHES '*[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]*' ) OR (oj MATCHES '????????[1-9][0-9 ][0-9 ]   '
              ) ) ) AND (oj NOT MATCHES '*/*/*/*' ) ) AND (oj NOT MATCHES '*[0-9] [0-9]*'
              ) ) AND (oj NOT MATCHES '*/[0-9][0-9][0-9]*' ) ) constraint dbo.oj_dirdoc
  ) extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode page;

###
create row type informix.eec
    (
    eecyear datetime year to year,
    eecnum integer,
    predpona varchar(7)
    );
###
CREATE FUNCTION informix.lessthanorequal(eec1 eec, eec2 eec) RETURNING BOOLEAN WITH(NOT VARIANT,NEGATOR=greaterthan);
IF eec1.eecyear IS NULL OR eec2.eecyear IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL::BOOLEAN;
ELIF eec1.eecyear < eec2.eecyear THEN RETURN 't';
ELIF eec1.eecyear > eec2.eecyear THEN RETURN 'f';
END IF
IF eec1.eecnum IS NULL OR eec2.eecnum IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL::BOOLEAN;
ELIF eec1.eecnum < eec2.eecnum THEN RETURN 't';
ELIF eec1.eecnum > eec2.eecnum THEN RETURN 'f';
END IF
IF eec1.predpona IS NULL AND eec2.predpona IS NULL THEN RETURN 't';
ELIF eec1.predpona < eec2.predpona THEN RETURN 't';
ELIF eec1.predpona > eec2.predpona THEN RETURN 'f';
ELIF eec2.predpona IS NULL THEN RETURN 't';
ELIF eec1.predpona IS NULL THEN RETURN 'f';
ELSE RETURN 't';
END IF
END FUNCTION;
###
create view dbo.dirdoc1 (typv,predpona,eecyear,eecnum,popivaz) as 
   select
        x0.typv,
        min(row(x1.eecyear,x1.eecnum,x1.predpona)::eec).predpona,
        min(row(x1.eecyear,x1.eecnum,x1.predpona)::eec).eecyear,
        min(row(x1.eecyear,x1.eecnum,x1.predpona)::eec).eecnum,
        max(x0.popivaz) 
    from
        dbo.typv x0,
    outer(dbo.dirdoc x1) where
        (x0.typv = x1.typv) 
    group by
        x0.typv;
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, but it would help if you could post the type of the columns that are being used and the definition of the user defined cast from ROW to the user defined type "eec" and the definition of the user defined type "eec".

Comment: Hello @LuísMarques, I added steps to replicate the issue to the original post. It really seems to me like a bug. It works in FC7W1, but does not work in FC10.

Comment: Tested your example on Informix 14.10.FC9W1 ( rocky linux 9.1 ), it worked without errors. Upgraded to Informix 14.10.FC10 and I get the error you got: `# 9952: Aggregate within a ROW in a SELECT projection list is not allowed.`. Using `finderr` for the error -9952 that shows on the CLI client ( `dbaccess` ) gives another error: `Message number -9952 not found.` . If you have a support contract with IBM, open a defect ticket (APAR) with them.

Comment: Thank you @LuísMarques , I created a ticket with IBM support. Thank you for your help/testing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been identified as idsdb00112189 and will be fixed in version 14.10 xC11 (expected in Q1/2024).